# What does OCaml exactly do when I say `let x = 1`, related to 31 bits

Tags: ocaml

Assume the system is 32 bits.

For a word, OCaml reserves the least significant bit to identify it is a pointer or an integer. So for an integer, there are only 31 bits effective.

I wish to know what OCaml does exactly for this conversion.

---

For example, if I do `let x = 1`, does OCaml do the followings?

1. Get the normal 1 in 32 bits: `0000...0001`
2. Shift it to left for 1 bit: `0000...0010`
3. Adding an `1` to it to make it appear like an integer: `0000...0011`

Am I correct?

But if this is the case, how does OCaml deal with negative integer such as `let x = min_int`?

1. Get the normal min_int in 32 bits: `1000...000`
2. Shift it to left for 1 bit: `000...000`
3. Adding an `1`: `000...0001`

Then the negative sign is lost, right?

---

In addition, how about the reversed process, i.e., what will OCaml do when it find a word in heap is an integer?

Comment: OCaml's `min_int` is `01000…000`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq yes, I know, the value should be `010...000`, I am just trying to find out the conversion process

Comment: You described the conversion process in your question (except with the wrong value for `min_int`: `min_int`'s real value is `010...000`, shift it to the left and add one gives `10…0001` for the unboxed encoding. The sign bit is right in its place.

Comment: @PascalCuoq So you mean, if I say `let x = -1073741824 (* min_int value *)`, OCaml will assume first that the sign bit must be on the 2nd most significant bit, and do 2's complement based on 31 bits?

Comment: @PascalCuoq I wrote in my question about `min_int` that way is because I thought OCaml would assume 32 bits first, then do the shift and add.

Comment: I think what happens is that any literal value encountered by the parser is translated to its valid boxed representation (shifted with the lsb set). If you give the parser a value which overflows, it is not accepted by the parser, and thus doesn't find its way in the internal representation of the code.

Comment: When a regular integer operation is performed, the compiler will translate the equivalent literal (`+`, `*`, etc) to the intrinsic code which does the right sequence of transformation on the values to retrieve the real integer (mask & shift right), perform the original instruction, and then transform back the result to the  memory representation value (shift left & lsb set).

Comment: As correctly pointed out by @PascalCuoq, the values for `min_int` and `max_int` are the rightful 31 bits integer maximum and minimum, so they do fit the runtime representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a symmetric issue exists for large positive values. You will convert the sign of  `max_int` as well.

Rather than left shift, think of the conversion as: `x * 2 + 1`

So, your representable numbers are limited to `min_int / 2` to `max_int / 2` [due to the representation of integers using twos complement, this is not really symmetric, the real limits are `min_int / 2 - 1` to `max_int / 2`]

The conversion back to integer is simply `m / 2`

Most processors have an "arithmetic shift" instruction that shifts right preserving (duplicating) the sign bit.

Comment: if I say `let x = -1073741824 (* min_int value *)`, OCaml will allocate a 32 bits word, assume first that the sign bit must be on the 2nd most significant bit, and do 2's complement based on 31 bits?

Comment: The binary representation of `-1073741824` is `0b1100000000000000` -- note that the two most significant bits are identical. This condition is true for all numbers that can be shifted left by one and not "lose" their sign.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "do 2's complement" -- the value `-1073741824` should be in 2's complement to start with; then it's just a matter of shifting left and adding one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some OCaml code (ints.ml):

```
let x = 1
let y = min_int
```

Here is the code generated for i386 (32-bit) architecture:

```
    .text
    .align  4
    .globl  _camlInts__entry
_camlInts__entry:
    subl    $12, %esp
L100:
    movl    $0x3, _camlInts
    movl    $0x80000001, _camlInts + 4
    movl    $0x1, %eax
    addl    $12, %esp
    ret
```

So (A) OCaml representation for 1 is 0b11 and for `min_int` is 0b1000....1. (B) The generated code doesn't "do" anything other than load the value (i.e., the int value isn't computed at run time from the usual integer value).

To add two OCaml int values: clear lowest bit of one of them, then add as usual.

Comment: could you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624671/will-ocaml-convert-multi-argument-function-to-currying-or-the-other-way-around