# Will OCaml convert multi-argument function to currying or the other way around?

Tags: ocaml

When I was learning OCaml essentials, I was told that every function in OCaml is actually a function with only one parameter. A multi-argument function is actually a function that takes one argument and returns a function that takes the next argumetn and returns ....

This is currying, I got that.

**So my question is**:

**case 1**

if I do

```
let plus x y = x + y
```

Inside OCaml when it compiles, will OCaml change it to `let plus = fun x -> fun y -> x + y`?

---

or the other way around that

**case 2**

If I do

```
let plus = fun x -> fun y -> x + y
```

OCaml will convert it to `let plus x y = x + y`?

---

Which case is true? What's the benifit or optimisation OCaml compiler has done in the correct case?

In addition, if *case 2* is true, then what is the point to consider OCaml is doing currying? I mean it actually does the opposite way, right?

This question is actually related to [Understand Core's `Fn.const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120623/understand-cores-fn-const/23120937#comment43668852_23120937)

Comment: `let plus x y = x + y` IS syntactic sugar for `let plus = fun x -> fun y -> x + y`. The second is how the first is defined in the language. There is no "change" because they are the same. As Jeffrey Scofield's answer says, a "non-curried" version would be `let plus (x, y) = x + y`

Comment: I just remembered those undocumented parameters of `ocamlc` (which also happen to work with *ocaml*!),  which makes the compiler dumps representations of the code at different stages of compilations. Quite interesting to compare the way code is being translated throughout the compilation process, I wanted to mention them here (`-dparsetree` etc.), but it seems it's been mentioned in one of the answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `let plus x y = x + y` and `let plus = fun x -> fun y -> x + y` will be compiled to the same code:

```
camlPlus__plus:
    leaq    -1(%rax, %rbx), %rax
    ret
```

Yes, exactly two assembler instructions, without any prologues and epilogues.

OCaml compiler performs several steps of optimizations, and actually "thinks" in a different categories. For example, both functions are represented with the same lambda code:

```
(function x y (+ x y))
```

I think, that according to the lambda above, you may think that OCaml compiler transforms to a non-curried version.

### Update

I would also like to add a few words about the core's `const` function. Suppose we have two semantically equivalent representations of the const function:

```
let const_xxx c = (); fun _ -> c
let const_yyy c _ = c
```

in a lambda form they will be represented as:

```
(function c (seq 0a (function param c))) ; const_xxx
(function c param c)                     ; const_yyy
```

So, as you can see, `const_xxx` is indeed compiled in a curried form.

But the most interesting question, is why it is worth to write it in a such obscure code. Maybe there're some clues in assembly output (amd64):

```
camlPlus__const_xxx_1008:
    subq    $8, %rsp
.L101:
    movq    %rax, %rbx                    ; save c into %rbx (it was in %rax)
.L102:  
    subq    $32, %r15                     ; allocate memory for a closure
    movq    caml_young_limit(%rip), %rax  ; check
    cmpq    (%rax), %r15                  ; that we have memory, if not
    jb      .L103                         ; then free heap and go back
    leaq    8(%r15), %rax                 ; load closure address to %rax
    movq    $3319, -8(%rax)
    movq    camlPlus__fun_1027(%rip), %rdi
    movq    %rdi, (%rax)
    movq    $3, 8(%rax)
    movq    %rbx, 16(%rax)                ; store parameter c in the closure
    addq    $8, %rsp             
    ret                                   ; return the closure
.L103:  call    caml_call_gc@PLT
.L104:  jmp .L102
```

What about `const_yyy`? It is compiled simply as:

```
camlPlus__const_yyy_1010:
    ret
```

Just return the argument. So, it is assumed that the actual point of optimization, is that in `const_xxx` the closure creation is compiled inside the function and should be fast. On the other hand, `const_yyy` doesn't expect to be called in a curried way, so if you will call it without all the needed parameters, then compiler needs to add the code that creates a closure in the point of `const_yyy` partial application (i.e., to perform all the operations in the `const_xxx` every time you call `const_xxx x`).

To conclude, `const` optimization creates a function that is optimized for partial application. Although, it comes with cost. A non-optimized `const` function will outperform the optimized if they are called with all parameters. (Actually my parameter even droped a call to `const_yyy` when I applied it with two args.

Comment: I believe your answer would be awesome, just I am not familiar with assembling languages. could you please somehow convert the meaning to more natural?

Comment: This is an awesome answer if one dives into it

Comment: could you please also explain with details about 1). your assembly output is on function application or function declaration? 2). Why `const_yyy` is a no-op. I mean I can't understand it properly. You mean compiler just do nothing on `const_yyy`? then where is the part of the code for `const_yyy`?

Comment: this is function declaration. `const_yyy` is compiled to a single instruction `ret` that corresponds to C `return x;` instruction. Function application depends heavily on what you're doing, for example if you're applying `const_yyy x y` then compiler even do not perform a call to it, and drop it. But if the application is partial, then compiler will embed all the stuff from `const_xxx` function, starting from `.L102` till `.L104` at the point of application.

Answer (score 5):

As far as the semantics of the OCaml language is concerned both of those definitions are completely equivalent definitions of a curried function. There's no such thing as a multi-argument function in the semantics of the OCaml language.

However the implementation is a different matter. Specifically the current implementation of the OCaml language supports multi-argument functions in its internal representation. When a curried function is defined a certain way (i.e. as `let f x y = ...` or `let f = fn x -> fn y -> ...`), this will be compiled to a multi-argument function internally. However if it is defined differently (like `let f x = (); fn y -> ...` in the linked question), it will be compiled to a curried function. This is only an optimization and does not affect the semantics of the language in any way. All three ways of defining a curried function are semantically equivalent.

Regarding your specific question about what gets turned into what: Since the transformation isn't from one piece of OCaml code into another piece of OCaml code, but rather from OCaml code to an internal representation, I think the most accurate way to describe it would be to say that the OCaml compiler turns both `let plus x y = x + y` and `let plus = fn x -> fn y -> x + y` into the same thing internally, not that it turns one into the other.

Comment: could you please give more details on that `same thing internally`? or refer me to some articles? It is very hard to google this specific

Comment: I guess I was confused by the term `multi-argument function`. i thought `let f x y = ...` is a `multi-argument function`. But it seems you refer `multi-argument function` to something internally, am I right?

Comment: @JacksonTale Exactly. In the OCaml language there's no such thing as a multi-argument function - only curried functions and tupled functions. However both in the internal representations used in the OCaml compiler and of course in machine code multi-argument functions exist and are much more efficient than either curried or tupled functions when the function is not partially applied (or, in case of a tupled function, called with an actual tuple).

Comment: Ok, now totally understand what you are saying. I have to mark ivg's answer as correct one as his answer has given more details, but your answer is also awesome and explains a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Both case 1 and case 2 are curried functions. Here is the non-curried version:

```
let plus (x, y) = x + y
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I learned that the native compiler will optimize your code, what I expect it to do. But here is the bytecode compiler:

```
let plus1 x y = x + y
let plus2 = fun x y -> x + y
let plus3 = function x -> function y -> x + y
```

treated with `ocamlc -c -dinstr temp.ml` gives me:

```
       branch L4
        restart
L1:     grab 1
        acc 1
        push
        acc 1
        addint
        return 2
        restart
L2:     grab 1
        acc 1
        push
        acc 1
        addint
        return 2
        restart
L3:     grab 1
        acc 1
        push
        acc 1
        addint
        return 2
```

which means the result is **exactly the same**, it is only a syntax difference. And the arguments are taken one by one.

Btw, one more syntax point: `fun` can be written with n arguments, `function` only with one.

From the conceptual point of view I would largely favor `function x -> function y ->` over the others.

Comment: the lambda representation is used by both native and bytecode backends, so usually it is enough to view the -dlambda output. But anyway, thanks for pointing on it